# Trying to wrap a php variable in single quotes

Tags: php

I am trying to wrap a `variable` in single quotes in `PHP`. This is my code:

```
$my_post = array(
            'post_title' => $orderRequestCode.' - ' . $customerName,
            'post_content' => $orderContent,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_author' => "'".$user_ID."'",
            'post_type' => 'orders'
            );
```

Currently `var_dump($my_post)` outputs:

```
array (size=5)
  'post_title' => string '2014-06-13-15-13-52 - xxxxxxx' (length=35)
  'post_content' => string 'Order Code: 2014-06-13-15-13-52
   Customer Name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
   Customer Email: xxx@xxxx.xx
   Order Items: 
   Stock Code: Q20-50-6101 Quantity: 12
   Comments: 
' (length=162)
  'post_status' => string 'draft' (length=5)
  'post_author' => string ''1'' (length=3)     <--------------- should be '1'
  'post_type' => string 'orders' (length=6)
```

This line:

```
'post_author' => string ''1'' (length=3)
```

Needs to be:

```
'post_author' => string '1' (length=3)
```

Comment: var dump will always enclose strings in quotes. Your string is 3 chars long, the other two quotes are added for dumping clarity

Comment: What does `'post_author' => $user_ID,` give you?

Comment: AFAIK you could just do `'post_author' => "'$user_ID'"`. PHP will parse the $user_ID since it's inside the double quotes `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're telling PHP to create a 3-character string:

```
$x = 1;

$y = "'" . $x . "'";
$y = ' 1 '
     1 2 3
```

Since it's a string, it will get wrapped by OTHER `'` as well when you do your dump. If your ID is an integer, and you want it to be treated as a string, then you could something as simple as:

```
 'post_author' => (string)$user_ID // cast to string
or
 'post_author' => '' . $user_ID; // concatentate with empty string
```

Answer (score 4):

The outside quotes in your `var_dump` aren't really part of the string, hence the length being 3, not 5.  If you echo your string it will be `'1'`